# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap

Tags: android, netty

I am using http://fyrecloud.com/amsler#mysql_replication for replicate mysql with sqlite but when I tried to run it I faced this error after clicking the start sync button

```
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at com.fyrecloud.amsler.Synchronizer.init(Synchronizer.java:67)
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at com.fyrecloud.amsler.Synchronize.onCreate(Synchronize.java:54)
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1089)
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-31 11:36:35.243: E/AndroidRuntime(7158):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding 'exported="true"' to .classpath file so that it become `<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="netty-3.2.6.Final.jar"/>`

but I didn't understand what was the problem ?