# Exception in thread "main" - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, program-entry-point, bootstrapping

After using `java -jar tracker-server.jar "configuration.xml"`

I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap
            at org.traccar.Main.main(Main.java:26)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
            ... 1 more
```

I found only its some about third party library. But I'm not friendly with Java.

Comment: try this $java -jar tracker-server.jar configuration.xml

Comment: `-bash: -jar: command not found`

Comment: Witch platform are you in? Windows? Java version? What the content of configuration.xml? What is it use for?

Comment: Linux Debian. `java -version` prints: `java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
`

Answer (score 0):

The ClassNotFoundException is caused by there soem jar file missing from the classpath. Search for the jar what includes the missing class and make it available for the enviroment.

See this thread: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965600/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-jboss-netty-bootstrap-clientbootstrap)

Comment: What do you mean? I tryed download netty and use `java -cp netty.jar -jar tracker-server.jar "configuration.xml` but without change.

Comment: Can you find org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap in the netty.jar file?

Comment: No, It's in io/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap

Comment: java -jar netty.jar org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap What the JVM says? Still not found?

Comment: It says `3.2.5.Final-a96d88c`

Comment: Please set your full path to your jar file like: java -cp /tmp/netty.jar -jar tracker-server.jar "configuration.xml" It seems JVM can not find the jar what you have set in the classpath.

Comment: When i use full path `/root/traccar/netty.jar`, all is same